# Formatting one page

Tags: css

How do I  format a paragraph on one page without affecting paragraphs on another page
For example I made my homepage index.html and thats ok but for the next page I want to apply new effects to the text layout.  So how to speak to that particular body of text?
It will have a larger font size for the first word and then smaller for the body and this will be repeated several times.

Comment: use divs and classes http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Why don't you use specific css in each page `head`? Or you can say `body.class1 { ... }` ... `body.classn { ... }` in your css file and `<body class="class1">` ... `<body class="classn">` in each of your html pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the body tag `<body class="home">` then you will be able to style all elements uniquely within that page by using the body class.

so as an example:

```
body.home p {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Aaron I think that helps alot,  now for more experimenting to try to learn the way this all works !

Comment: @JUST if you could click the check mark next to my answer to mark it as correct then please.